# How to read text from inputTextarea as javascript object

Tags: javascript

I want to give the java script object structure as text input into the `inputTextarea` and i want a `var` to read that as object. My object structure is like below. Instead of giving this in the `inputTextarea` i can give this directly in my `xhtml` page as `var obj={ onchange: ...` but that i don't want. Because there are difficulties in parsing the `xml` tags also, else it will throw some tag errors. Is that possible to read the text from `inputTextarea` as `var` object instead of reading as `string` .

```
{
onchange: function(){
console.log("I been changed now!")
},
validate: function(obj){
console.log("I be validatin' now!")
},
elements: {
"list": {
menu: [{
caption: "Append an <item>",
action: Xonomy.newElementChild,
actionParameter: "<item/>"
}]
},
"item": {
menu: [{
caption: "Add @label=\"something\"",
action: Xonomy.newAttribute,
actionParameter: {name: "label", value: "something"},
hideIf: function(jsElement){
return jsElement.hasAttribute("label");
}
}, {
caption: "Delete this <item>",
action: Xonomy.deleteElement
}, {
caption: "New <item> before this",
action: Xonomy.newElementBefore,
actionParameter: "<item/>"
}, {
caption: "New <item> after this",
action: Xonomy.newElementAfter,
actionParameter: "<item/>"
}],
canDropTo: ["list"],
attributes: {
"label": {
asker: Xonomy.askString,
menu: [{
caption: "Delete this @label",
action: Xonomy.deleteAttribute
}]
}
}
}
}
}
```

Comment: Can you take a moment and properly tab your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem with

```
eval('(' + myinputtext + ')');
```

Answer (score 1):

As far I understand you need to read a textarea content as a JavaScript object.

If the textarea content is a valid JSON, you can transform the textarea content into by calling `JSON.parse`.

If the textarea content is not a valid JSON, but some kind of arbitrary JavaScript object representation, you can use `eval` to transform it into a JavaScript object. However, take into account that using eval is a security concern, you should not use it unless the input is coming from a trusted source.

```js
const textArea = document.getElementById('demo');

// this will work only if textarea content is a valid JSON
// const myObject = JSON.parse(textArea.textContent);

// this following is insecure, use on your own risk
const myObject = eval(`(${textArea.textContent})`);

console.log(typeof myObject);
console.log(myObject);
```

```html
<textarea id="demo">
{ a: 1 }
</textarea>
```

Comment: It is working fine in console. But in the original code it looks like **eval(`()`)** while inspecting instead of **eval(`(${mytext})`)** . Why this missing occurs while running?

Comment: I have checked your answer, glad that you have figured it out. Looks like the target environment does not support template literals, that would explain why string concatenation solved the issue.